# Android Access Image From PC Using URL

Tags: android, port

I know how to access image from remote server using URL, but I need to access image from local PC using url. I found same kind of question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465391/cant-load-image-from-my-local-server-on-android) and I can use the url like `http://IP:PORT/image.png` , I know my IP address but, what should be the port number ?.

Thanks in advance..........

Answer (score 1):

Http by default runs on port 80, and you will not need to specify it in that case.

You only need to specify it if your web server on your PC is using a different one.

Comment: but when I give the url like http://192.168.1.206/home/haris/Desktop/image_png.png the image is not loading

Comment: When I set up my apache web server under linux, acessing a file 192.168.1.206/image.png defaulted to looking for the file /var/www/html/image.png on the server. Check your web server setup, and possibly also try an app to determine if you can ping the server or not from the LAN.

Comment: Hi Adrian, thanks for replay. So do I need to install web server on my PC. If so what are procedure should I tkae for accessing my file using http, any links or tutorial....

Comment: Well that would depend upon your pc, but an open source web server is available at http://httpd.apache.org/ which runs on UNIX and Windows. There is a tutorial at http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/install-apache-2-windows.shtml. You will also need to set up security for the PC to prevent unauthorised access from the internet. Once you have it working correctly then you should be able to access files from the PC using the same code you use to access them from the internet, just with a different url as you noted earlier.