# Access File Using http From Local Server

Tags: html, web-services, networking

I need to access some image file from my PC of any other PC in local. I have IP address of the server PC. I need to access the file (eg:img.png) at the server using http, Like `http://192.168.1.30/home/user/img.png`. So for accessing file from server do I need to install web server at the server side ?. And what are the procedure I have to follow on the server side?.
I want to do this in Linux.

Thanks in advance.......

Comment: I have tried from android using url like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465391/cant-load-image-from-my-local-server-on-android but the image is not displaying.

Comment: Also Is it possible if I type the entire url in browser, does it show ?

Comment: i have a doubt?that img resides in cloud server or in your local network shared pc?

Comment: the image in my pc, it is not shared or there is no cloud server

Comment: Did you ever get this solved?

Comment: I think you need to install Apache server https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0):

Change your hyperlink tag by

```
\\IPAddress\folder\filename
```

Comment: I want to do this in linux

Comment: hey @Haris try this and get back to me with an exception what you got... it's pretty hard to define your next step without knowing where you are?????

Comment: Hey Shankar with your answer I tried in browser, but server not found error

Comment: then try like this 'file://hostaddress/folder/filename '

Comment: Hi as said in the question I need it using http, because basically I need to access this file from my android phone.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31579/discussion-between-haris-and-shankar)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have python on your computer.(linux)

verify that you have linux by running `python -V` you should see something like v3.10
Navigate to the directory that you want to share files from
run `python -m http.server 8000`
Go to another device and access this newly created server by typing `http://ipaddress:8000`
You should see the files